# Npgsql - how to pass a table?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to pass a table. On the database side I'm using a composite type "type_detalle_ac", and on the vb side I'm trying to send a list with MapCompositeGlobally, this would be the code in vb:

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO, ByVal LD As List(Of E_DETALLE_AC))
NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally(Of List(Of E_DETALLE_AC))("type_detalle_ac")
Dim CONECTION As New NpgsqlConnection


Try
    CONECTION.ConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123;Database=ALURHE_DB"
    Dim COMMAND As New NpgsqlCommand
    With COMMAND
        .Connection = CONECTION
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .CommandText = "SP_ADM_ARTEFACTO"

        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_serie", P.P_SERIE)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_artefacto", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_modelo", P.P_MODELO)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_marca", P.P_MARCA)

        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_detalle", LD)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_usuario", P.P_USUARIO)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_id_artefacto", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_operacion", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)

        End With


    CONECTION.Open()

    COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
    CONECTION.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        CONECTION.Close()
    End If

    Throw ex
End Try
End Sub
```

this is the code of the class:

```
Public Class E_DETALLE_AC
   Public Property id_componente As Integer

   Public Property precio As Decimal
   Public Property cantidad As Integer
   Public Property sub_total As Decimal
End Class
```

but I get the following error:

> PostgreSQL composite type public.type_detalle_ac contains field id_componente which could not match any on CLR type List`1

What could I do to send a table? I would appreciate your help

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible, there isn't a type implemented in the provider for that. Keep looking, maybe I'm wrong but you could fill a temp table with the data that you would have passed to the procedure and then work with that temp table in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following and it worked, this link:

https://gist.github.com/jakejscott/eee8a257fceabbec537c92a8604a516e

In part of MapCompositeGlobally I had to put only the class and not the list. The list would put it in the "v_detalle" parameter simply.

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO, ByVal LD As List(Of E_DETALLE_AC))
    NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally(Of E_DETALLE_AC)("type_detalle_ac")
    Dim CONECTION As New NpgsqlConnection


    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123;Database=ALURHE_DB"
        Dim COMMAND As New NpgsqlCommand
        With COMMAND
            .Connection = CONECTION
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "sp_adm_artefacto"

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_serie", P.P_SERIE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_artefacto", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_modelo", P.P_MODELO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_marca", P.P_MARCA)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_detalle", LD)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_usuario", P.P_USUARIO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_id_artefacto", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("v_tipo_operacion", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)
        End With


        CONECTION.Open()

        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

On the database side, declare v_detalle of type type_detalle_ac but as array, I also use unnest in select

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
v_serie character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_tipo_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_modelo character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_marca integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_detalle type_detalle_ac[] DEFAULT NULL::type_detalle_ac[],
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_id_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;

BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID_ARTEFACTO),0) INTO VL_ID_ARTEFACTO FROM ARTEFACTO;
        VL_ID_ARTEFACTO:=VL_ID_ARTEFACTO+1;

        INSERT INTO ARTEFACTO (ID_ARTEFACTO,SERIE,TIPO_ARTEFACTO,MODELO,MARCA,USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        VALUES (VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,v_serie,v_tipo_artefacto,v_modelo,v_marca,V_USUARIO,NOW());

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW()
        FROM unnest(V_DETALLE);

    END IF;

END;


$BODY$;
```